# SQL Server query does not return results when searching for lower(string) <> upper(string)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some zip codes. Some of them contain lowercase characters.

```
select ID, Zipcode, LOWER(Zipcode), UPPER(Zipcode)
from Addresses
where ID = 99
```

[image]

However, when I try to get all zip codes that have some lowercase characters, then I do not get any results:

```
select ID, Zipcode, LOWER(Zipcode), UPPER(Zipcode)
from Addresses
where LOWER(Zipcode) <> UPPER(Zipcode)
```

[image]

I would expect to see (at least) the record with ID=99 now, but I do not get any results at all. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: What is the collation of the `ZipCode` column?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: WHERE Zipcode <> upper(Zipcode)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS   ... this will return rows containing lowercase characters

Comment: Then use case sensitive collation when you compare the values `... WHERE LOWER(Zipcode COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) <> UPPER(Zipcode COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) ... `

Comment: The `CI` part of your collation means `Case Insensitive`, so it doesn't matter what you do with `upper` or `lower`, `a` equals `A`.  As already stated, use a `CS` (`Case Sensitive`) collation when comparing.  (If you're interested, the `AS` means `Accent Sensitive`, so `a` does NOT equal `á`)

Comment: Better yet: change the collation of the actual column.

Comment: Even better, don't change collation and think about why you want to have case sensitive search, no humans (except c programmers) care for it